# Make a type from enum values

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

I have an enum (in javascript with typescript) and I want to convert the values into a single type.

My enum:

```js
enum StatusCodes {
    SUCCESS = "success",
    FAILED = "failed"
}
```

The type I want to make automatically, using some generics:

```js
type StatusCode = "success" | "failed"
```

Comment: Why not just use `StatusCodes` as the type?

Comment: `type StatusCode = StatusCodes.SUCCESS | StatusCodes.FAILED`.

Comment: It's already in a single type. If you want strings instead of an enum, just use strings in the first place.